# Deploy to Azure from command prompt

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I'm currently having problems with deploying from inside Visual Studio (basically Visual Studio crashes when creating the package). I know how to build a package myself with cspack, so I made a batch file that build the project and creates the package. But is it also possible to deploy the package from command line? For now I'm using the Management Portal, but it would be nice if I could also put this in a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy using the Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets found here: http://wappowershell.codeplex.com.

Use Update-Deployment or New-Deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Besides using PowerShell, you can also use **CSManage.exe** if you're working with batch files: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c

Example:

```
csmanage.exe /create-deployment /slot:staging /hosted-service:MyHostedService /name:MyDeployment /label:MyLabel /config:./ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /package:http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/packages/MyApplication.cspkg
```